# Notification error: APN invalid token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I stopped receiving the push notifications after the certificate got expired and new certificate has been created. I've updated the p12 certificate on the server.

I'm using Pusher application to debug the issue further and I tried importing the p12 certificate with the device token. It says "APN invalid token".

Same method works for my other application.

[image: Notification Error: APN invalid token]
Please help me with this I'm not an expert, I tried searching the solution in SO but couldn't find the exact problem.

Any tips will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely the reason will be - using sandbox device token with production  APNS server or vice versa. Can you please re-check & make sure that both app & server are on same production environment?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check project configuration - it has to be Release not Debug.

Comment: Reading around, it seems this is not exactly the case. If your app is built in release mode, you need to use a production certificate, key, and APN token. Alternatively, if you build in debug mode, you need to use a sandbox certificate, key, and APN token. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491719/how-do-i-make-my-debug-app-version-receive-production-push-notifications-on-ios/46118155#46118155